# How to apply word2vec on images?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, word2vec

I have been studying word2vec model by Google. I was able to generate vectors for text word corpus for maximum 300 dimensions. It is a very impressive tool and accuracy goes much further, on big data.

I am curious, is there any way to use word2vec to generate vectors on grayscale images. I am sure the approach is same, you generate vectors based on pixel intensity and then compute a cosine similarity.

I am trying to do build a model to compute similarity distance on grayscale images. Any library is capable of doing this besides word2vec or glove that works on text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word2vec is not a good model for images, however I think what you really need is a [bag of word model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision). In a basic method of image comparison, you convert images to a list of key point features (e.g. SIFT, SURF or etc.), then you match clusters of points with each other (e.g. [FLANN](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html)).

The high amount of features in an image and uncertainty of each point representation makes it difficult to use a basic one layer network learning such as word2vec for image recognition. You may find better examples in this [tutorials](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_table_of_contents_ml/py_table_of_contents_ml.html).

**UPDATE after 3 years**: I should also mention ConvNets and several pre-trained models available now which you can extract visual features from pixels.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you that word2vec is very impressive tool, but this model is trained by **predicting the next word** in some article or news. All in all, I think that using word2vec on **image** does not make sense.

You can use [skimage](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.html) to do some image measure. e.g [skimage-measure](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html)

Comment: Word2vec dumps vector of words, whereas with images we are looking at pixel intensity. I would like to compute 255 dimensional vector on pixel intensity in every image (say for 1 million images and then predict how similar the images are). The concept is same, you find the frequency of each pixel intensity (gives a vector). Then compute cosine similarity with a given image, so see how much similarity the images have.

Comment: You mean you think that sequential pixel can predict can imply what is next pixel?

Comment: Yes sequential or surrounding pixels just like words.